# .htaccess RewriteRule to path without changing URL in smarty (php)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Actually i have this problem:

The url that comes for  internal page are like
**`http://example.co.in/page.php?id=2`**

What i want actually is like
**http://example.co.in/AboutUs**

Is it possible by using only .htaccess ?  My .htaccess code are given just below but  it gives the output like this
`http://example.co.in/page/2`

```
Options -MultiViews  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/page\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [R=301,L]  

RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I tried a lot by but not get succeeded!

Comment: Don't use a rule for each page, just rewrite all non-file requests to `index.php`, then look up the path part of the URL in a simple array to include pages by ID. It's called routing.

Comment: Hii @Walf   ! Actually i can't use routing in it and i have to do this only for the two pages so Is it possible to manipulate/rewrite  url   only by .htaccess ?

Comment: You can't add 5 lines of PHP? Not even in a new file?

Comment: Sorry @Walf -- but i never used routing before and don't have idea about it!

Comment: Routing just means: look at the URL, then decide which page to serve based on its contents. I'm sure you could do that. "i have to do this only for the two pages" until people add more pages? then maybe just a few more?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a rule for each page. Here is one to get you started based on your example:

**/AboutUs**

```
Options -MultiViews  
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^AboutUs$ page.php?id=2 [QSA]
```

This will preserve any query string that may be used, adding the `id=2`. It's an internal rewrite so visiting `AboutUs` will actually serve `page.php?id=2` which sounds like what you want. Add one `RewriteRule` for each page. It's to go in a .htaccess file as requested.

**/page.php?id=2**

If you also want to stop `page.php?id=2` from working, and have it redirect to `AboutUs`, add this set of two directives for each page.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=2(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ AboutUs? [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect with extra query string parameters provided, but the whole query string is dropped and not passed on (the `?` after `AboutUs`).

**Notes**

Obviously change the relevant parts for each page you create rules for (the id number and the AboutUs part) but leave the other parts exactly as they are for each one.

Comment: Hii @user2493235    --i tried your first half code but still getting the url like   `http://example.co.in/page.php?id=2`

Comment: The first half will only make `/AboutUs` work. You need the second half to redirect from `/page.php?id=2` to `/AboutUs`.

Answer (score 0):

Hiii, all ! Thanks everyone for your support and suggestions.
Below are the codes that works for me what i exactly want. Hope it helps anyone if needed.

```
# Tell PHP that the mod_rewrite module is ENABLED.  
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On  
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#FOR INTERNAL PAGES(rewrite "/page.php?name=about us" to "AboutUs")  

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&\s]+)$  
RewriteRule ^(?:page\.php|)$ /%1? [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&\s]+)&name=([^&\s]+)$  
RewriteRule ^(?:page\.php|)$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^([^\s\/]+)/?$ page.php?name=$1&r [L,QSA]
```